# I don’t get the kernel stack right by simpleperf

Tags: android, linux, stack-trace, perf

1. I get the `perf.data` from the Android device (kernel 4.9) by the following command:

   ```
   simpleperf record -p 291 -o /data/local/tmp/perf.data --duration 5 -g -f 22750
   ```
2. Parse the `perf.data` to `perf.html` by

   ```
   report_html.py report_html.py -i perf.data -o perf.html
   ```
3. Check the flow of the `mmc_blk_end_queued_req` function in the
   `perf.html`. I can't get the right flow about the

   > `mmc_blk_end_queued_req`. The stack should be `mmc_blk_end_queued` →
   > `req_bio_endio` → `bio_end`, but `mmc_blk_end_queued` → `bio_end`
   > from the *flame graph*.

Take a look here:

[image]

Comment: Hello, I can't fully understand the problem. Your screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGcdr.png has "blk_update_request -> blk_endio -> ext4_end_bio" callchain which looks normal as blk_update_request has call to req_bio_endio which may call bio_endio: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9/source/block/blk-core.c#L2539 & https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9/source/block/blk-core.c#L142. Some functions are inlined and I'm not sure will simpleperf get information from any dwarf for kernel code to find what was inlined.

Comment: req_bio_endio  isn`t inlined,  as below:                                                                static void req_bio_endio(struct request *rq, struct bio *bio, unsigned int nbytes, int error)

Comment: I don't think you can tell if a function's been inlined just by looking at the function signature. The 'inline' tag isn't present, but compilers can and do still inline code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get it. It should be simpler to merge the stack, because the stacks have the same instruction pointer (ip) and stack pointer (sp).

---

From *[Simpleperf](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/simpleperf/doc/README.md#why-we-cant-always-get-complete-dwarf-based-call-graphs)*:

> Why we can't always get complete DWARF-based call graphs

> DWARF-based call graphs are generated by unwinding thread stacks. When a sample is generated, up to 64 KB stack data is dumped by the kernel. By unwinding the stack based on dwarf information, we get a callchain. But the thread stack can be much longer than 64 KB. In that case, we can't unwind to the thread start point.

> To alleviate the problem, simpleperf joins callchains after recording them. If two callchains of a thread have an entry containing the same ip and sp address, then simpleperf tries to join them to make the callchains longer. In that case, the longer we run, the more samples we get. This makes it more likely to get complete callchains, but it's still not guaranteed to get complete call graphs.

Comment: per-process kernel stacks are small, like 16k.  (e.g. https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-arm-kernel/patch/1374601951-4091-1-git-send-email-fkan@apm.com/ was the patch that bumped it up from 8 to 16k for AArch64 for mainline Linux.)  User-space stacks are much larger, though, like `ulimit -s` (perhaps 8MiB).

Comment: @PeterCordes , Thanks for your answer. Do you know how to get the complete stack by simpleperf ?

Comment: No, I've never used it, or done any Android development.  (Or much kernel profiling even on x86-64.)